# Applying for UK Visa after overstaying

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, overstaying

So I was a student in the UK, all the way from foundation year to post grad. Lived in the UK for 6 years in total, never had an issue, never got in trouble.

However after I finished my post grad I overstayed by one day, but then left voluntarily with my own funds. This was 3 years ago.

This week I applied for a tourist visa for the UK, and was denied due to my one day overstay.

My question is: where do I move on from here? Have I been banned permanently? Who/where can I contact to get some answers? Should I reapply or just appeal? I would appreciate any pointers. Thank you!

Comment: If you were banned you would have been told. For visa refusals we ask that you upload scans of the refusal notice that you received, with personal information blacked out, and we can help you understand exactly what parts of the regulations/law you were refused under and how to go about addressing these deficiencies in your application.

Comment: @Ingrid There is no right of appeal for a UK Standard Visitor visa. In cases where there has been an obvious mistake it is sometimes possible to ask for a review, however an overstay is normally grounds for either mandatory or discretionary refusal under Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal. A refusal solely for a one day overstay seems particularly harsh if all other aspects of your application were in order

Comment: Time healeth all wounds. This appears extremely harsh, give it another six months and reapply. We’re assuming you are grounded and financially secure in your country. What’s your citizenship? Married?

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn On what basis do you expect to get a different answer in six months? We don't even know how long ago the overstay was.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn You're right -- I missed the "three years ago" part. But still, I don't see how three years and six months is time to healeth a wound that wasn't healethed after three years.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn I agree that denying a visa for a one-day overstay seems harsh. However, suggesting that somebody have another roll of the dice and apply again is usually bad advice, especially as we haven't seen the refusal so we don't know the whole picture. Can you cite any official guidance saying that a very short overstay a few years ago shouldn't normally cause a visa to be rejected, or is it just that you, personally, feel that it is unjust? If you can cite official guidance, there is a strong possibility that other factors came into play and a second application would be rejected...

Comment: ... for the same reason, unless those issues were fixed. (And, by the way, Ingrid is a woman's name.)